# How to find which partition file belongs to in Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

How to find which partition file belongs to using Powershell ? Want to use this to find a partition which is mounted as accesspath so it doesn't have a DriveLetter assigned.

In Linux we can use following command to do this:

```
df /path/to/some/file.txt
```

I am aware that we can list partitions using Get-Partition, list volumes using Get-Volume or Get-WmiObject win32_volume, however I'm unable to find easy a programatic way to find a partition to which a particular file belongs to.

Comment: @facebook interesting code, however nothing in this code does what I require.

Comment: Well when you get to this, check it out and test with it here: https://justpaste.it/1cmfr but I'll be happy to adjust and/or add as an answer if you find helpful. I suppose you could make it a function, a script to pass the first argument to as I have commented out, or whatever. I need to get to other location with Linux Mint to play with `df` command output to make match 100% though.

Comment: @facebook your solution will work only if the driveletter is assigned to a partition, PSDrive.name for a Get-Item will not return right value if the partition is mounted on a directory (AccessPath).

Comment: What are you using in Windows to mount to a path rather than a drive letter? I don't think I've ever done that before but help refresh my memory. I'm not sure about `AccessPath` either but I forget things since I push so many different things thru my head every day.

Comment: I see even doing it this way shows a drive letter: https://www.howtogeek.com/98195/how-to-mount-a-hard-drive-as-a-folder-on-your-windows-pc/. I didn't know Windows mounted to folder paths like linux does—I thought Windows OS accessible "mounted" locations were drive letters only. I may be mistaken as I'm just not familiar with that functionality in Windows unless I'm forgetting about something. What file path are you referencing as the `df` tables the file path in your example so what is the file path in your Windows example?

Comment: Is this the [AccessPath](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/add-partitionaccesspath?view=win10-ps) you were referring to by chance—maybe this will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192483/assign-a-mount-point-folder-path-to-a-drive-using-powershell just trying to give you some ideas?

Comment: @facebook this is what I mean by AccessPath. In windows you are able to mount partition/volume to a directory similar as in Linux.

Comment: Closest to a solution which I got so far is:

gwmi win32_volume | where { "c:\path\to\a\file.txt".StartsWith( $_.name ,"CurrentCultureIgnoreCase") } | sort { $_.name.length } -desc | select -First 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67407/discussion-between-facebook-and-timb).

Answer (score 6):

We can get the list of mount points from the WMI class `Win32_MountPoint`. That gives us a mapping between volume paths and root directories. We can then figure out which mount point is most specific for a given file. Finally, we can use the volume ID from the mount point object to get some information on the volume itself. Here's the full script:

```
param (
    [string]$File
)
$fullPath = [string](Resolve-Path $File)
$bestMatch = ''
$bestMatchObj = $null
gwmi Win32_MountPoint | % {
    $_.Directory -match '="(.*)"' | Out-Null
    $mountDir = $matches[1].Replace('\\', '\')
    If (!$mountDir.EndsWith('\')) { $mountDir = $mountDir + '\' }
    If ($fullPath.StartsWith($mountDir, 'InvariantCultureIgnoreCase') -and $bestMatch.Length -lt $mountDir.Length) { 
        $bestMatch = $mountDir
        $bestMatchObj = $_
    }
}
$bestMatchObj.Volume -match '="(.*)"' | Out-Null
$volPath = $matches[1].Replace('\\', '\')
Get-Volume | ? { $_.Path -eq $volPath }
```

The `-match`-followed-by-`$matches` trick extracts the relevant parts of the WMI relationship strings. We have to unescape the backslashes, hence the replacement. Then, since only simple drive letter assignments have backslashes at the end of their `Directory` value, we need to add one if it's absent to avoid false positives on similarly-named mount points.

To use the script, save it as a PS1 file, e.g. `df.ps1`. To enable the execution of scripts on your system, follow the instructions in the Enabling Scripts section of [the PowerShell tag wiki](https://superuser.com/tags/powershell/info). Then you can run it like this:

```
.\df.ps1 -File C:\some\mounted\path\doc.txt
```

Results are of the same type as objects returned from any other use of `Get-Volume`:

```
DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining    Size
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------    ----
            <redacted>   NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                      1.93 GB 1.95 GB
```

Notice how it has no `DriveLetter`, since this particular file was actually on a different volume than the one that holds the root of my C drive.

Comment: +1. . . I wasn't sure if you'd be able to get to it or not. I tested with this: https://justpaste.it/1cmla but that's what I was able to come up with. Good job man!

Comment: Good job ! Very close to my solution given previously in comments: gwmi win32_volume | where { "c:\path\to\a\file.txt".StartsWith( $_.name ,"CurrentCultureIgnoreCase") } | sort { $_.name.length } -desc | select -First 1, it seems that there might not be a simpler solution to this problem as I was hoping :(

Comment: @TimB Glad I could help! If my answer completely solved the problem, you can click the checkmark next to it to [accept it](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer), indicating to future readers that it does the job. If there's anything that should be adjusted, please let me know.